# Unable to bind @Input to parent to child Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have the following configuration:

Parent Html

`<login-info [username]="userInformation"></login-info>`

parent component

```
userInformation:string;
```

child component

```
@Input username: string;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.username = this.loginInfoService.getLoginInformation();
    }
```

child html

```
<div>
    {{username}}
</div>
```

child service

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginInfoService {

    username:string;

    public getLoginInformation(): string {
        return this.username = "mike";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Can't bind to 'username' since it isn't a known property of 'login-
info'. 1. If 'login-info' is an Angular component and it has 
'username' input, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 
'login-info' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to 
the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (" 
<sa-route-breadcrumbs></sa-route-breadcrumbs> <login-info [ERROR ->]
[username]="userInformation"></login-info> </div> ")
```

-------------------------------Update 1------------------------

Created a `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({

    declarations: [LoginInformationComponent],

    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

})

export class RibbonModule{

}
```

Comment: Have you included the child component in the declarations of your module?

Comment: Can you post the code for `loginInfoService.getLoginInformation()` method?

Comment: @jhhoff02 please see updated post

Comment: @Summoner I do not have a module for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an input, you do not need to "fetch" the data, that is the job of the `@Input()`

So with

```
// note, should be brackets here
@Input() username: string;
```

you already get the value from the parent, and do not need to fetch it.

And using the child-components tag in parent, you need to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in your `ngModule` to tell Angular that it's a custom tag you have created. So add the following line to the ngModule, where you have declared your components (that is what your error message suggests).

```
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

So your `ngModule` should look something like this:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent...],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    // other stuff
    ....
})

export class YourModuleName{
}
```

Comment: I do not have a `NgModule` for this one. Simply a child passing information to the parent. Good catch on the `Input`

Comment: Well you have to have an app module with an ngmodule, otherwise your app wouldn't work ;)

Comment: I have one yes, I have several, just not for this directory.

Comment: Well, the same place where you have declared this parent component and childcomponent in `declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent]` you must have declared them **somehwhere** otherwise your components wouldn't load at all. So in that same module, add the last line in my answer ;)

Comment: Ok I am beginning to think I do not need `@Input` at all but when I just write `login-info></login-info> it blows up. So if I made a `@NgModule` imported the component it should work.

Comment: it blows up because it cannot recognize the tag `<login-info>` therefore you have to add the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to that module where you have declared your components, meaning this login-info component and your parentcomponent, whatever its name is.

Comment: You just "created" an module? You must have had one before, where you have declared at least your parentcomponent, as it wouldn't otherwise load at all. And btw, your child component must be declared as well. All components need to be declared!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134218/discussion-between-drew1208-and-ajt-82).

Comment: Are you interested in a job. Angular 4 and good pay. It is short term and on the side. Let me know